# Unable to make local repository with Github desktop

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

Whenever I try to create a local repository using Github Desktop, the following error occurs:

> Command failed: /Applications/GitHub Desktop.app/Contents/Resources/app/git/bin/git update-index --add --remove --replace -z --stdin

I'm using MacOS. What is this command trying to do and why would it be failing?